# compare actual and target get the respective value in other column using pandas or pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have a column work,cost ,actual and target

```
  work  cost  actual  target
0    A     2      14    56.0
1    B     2      21    67.0
2    B     3      32    67.0
3    B     4      32     NaN
4    A     3      56    56.0
5    A     4      82     NaN
```

if my actual value >target value it means it reached target then print the cost in new column 'cost_met' the cost row where actual >=target, if actual is less than target it means it not reach then print the cost of the last value but here in B we have 32 as actual value for two rows in that case take the first cost 3 using pandas,
Note:my target is null or else a single unique value
Note:group by column work

Expected output:

```
  work  cost  actual  target  cost_met
0    A     2      14    56.0         3
1    B     2      21    67.0         3
2    B     3      32    67.0         3
3    B     4      32     NaN         3
4    A     3      56    56.0         3
5    A     4      82     NaN         3
```

I applied

```
grouped_df = df_final1.groupby('work')
df_final1['new_column']=grouped_df.apply(lambda x: x['cost'].where(x['actual']>x['target'])).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: the second table updated it in question

Comment: There are missing scenarios. What happens when 2 or more actual > target per group?

Comment: we need to consider only the first cost where actual>target per group,no need to print other cost

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) with a custom function:

```
def get_cost(g):
    x = g.loc[g['actual'].ge(g['target']), 'cost']
    return x if len(x)>0 else g.dropna()['cost'].iloc[[-1]]

df['cost_met'] = df['work'].map(df.groupby('work').apply(get_cost).droplevel(1))
```

Output:

```
  work  cost  actual  target  cost_met
0    A     2      14    56.0         3
1    B     2      21    67.0         3
2    B     3      32    67.0         3
3    B     4      32     NaN         3
4    A     3      56    56.0         3
5    A     4      82     NaN         3
```

Comment: IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds i am facing this issue

Comment: please provide a reproducible example that reproduces the error

Comment: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-327014839274346> in <cell line: 5>()
      3     return x if len(x)>0 else df_final1.dropna()['cost'].iloc[[-1]]
      4 
----> 5 df_final1['cost_met'] = df_final1['work'].map(df.groupby('work').apply(get_cost).droplevel(1))